# Need help making an IF clause in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all I'm really new to WordPress and PHP (know a little of code but not web).

I'm making a site with an Apptheme's theme called classipress for classifieds. My page let's you post and AD in BTC or USD but the problem is that for BTC, I need several decimals (around 5) and with USD it just doesn't feel good seeing 5 decimal (specially five zeroes).

I'd like to know if someone could help me with an If clause since I read some manuals on WordPress and still can't figure out how to make it in this language.

The working code that always shows the 5 decimals is:

```
function cp_price_format( $price ) {
global $cp_options;

if ( is_numeric( $price ) ) {
    $decimals = ( $cp_options->hide_decimals || $price == 0 ) ? 0 : 5;
    $decimal_separator = $cp_options->decimal_separator;
    $thousands_separator = $cp_options->thousands_separator;

    $price = number_format( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousands_separator );
}

return $price;
}
```

If I were to change the `return $price` for `return floatval($price);`, it will ALWAYS erase the decimals, I need to only erase decimals if they are only zeroes.

I tried doing something like this:

```
function cp_price_format( $price ) {
global $cp_options;

if ( is_numeric( $price ) ) {
    $decimals = ( $cp_options->hide_decimals || $price == 0 ) ? 0 : 5;
    $decimal_separator = $cp_options->decimal_separator;
    $thousands_separator = $cp_options->thousands_separator;

    $price = number_format( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousands_separator );
}

if ($decimals ==0){ return floatval($price);}
else {return $price;}
}
```

But it didn't work at all... I guess its a problem with the `{}` or the commas, but can't figure it out just starting with WordPress...

I'd really appreciate if someone could do the `IF clause` for me so I can make it work and learn how to do it properly.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Well, when you call `cp_price_format` do you know what the currency is?

Answer (score 0):

`$num + 0` does the trick.

```
echo 125.00 + 0;   // Result = 125
echo '125.00' + 0; // Result = 125
echo 966.70 + 0;   // Result = 966.7
```